# Pine script: Adding two stocks volume values

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to take the total volume of two stocks and plot it. One of them started trading in 2022 and the other in 2021. I noticed the plot starts from 2022 skipping the volume for first stock in 2021.

```
indicator("tasi_p1", overlay=false,format=format.volume)

src  = request.security("TADAWUL:4164",timeframe.period,volume, barmerge.gaps_off)

src := src + 
 request.security("TADAWUL:2082",timeframe.period,volume, barmerge.gaps_off)

palette = close[1] > close ? color.red : color.green

plot(src,style=plot.style_histogram,color = palette)
```

My main goal is to plot the volume of group/sector of related stocks and use it in my strategy.

Also, I noticed same behavior in TradingView when adding the stock symbols in Symbol Search text field like "4164 + 2082" it skips 2021 part even the in candle chart.

Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because `4164` will return `NaN` as its volume before it started trading. Then you are trying to use this `NaN` value in your calculations which you shouldn't do.

Wrap your `src` into `nz()` and it will replace `NaN` with zeros.

```
//@version=5
indicator("tasi_p1", overlay=false,format=format.volume)

src  = request.security("TADAWUL:4164",timeframe.period,volume, barmerge.gaps_off)

src := nz(src) + 
 request.security("TADAWUL:2082",timeframe.period,volume, barmerge.gaps_off)

palette = close[1] > close ? color.red : color.green

plot(src,style=plot.style_histogram,color = palette)
```